# Closing OneNote Application from excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, onenote

I'm trying to Close the OneNote Application from VBA excel with this piece of code:

```
Sub closeOneNote()
                Dim oneNoteApp As Object
                On Error Resume Next
                Set oneNoteApp = GetObject(, "OneNote.Application")
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                oneNoteApp.Quit
                Else
                Err.Clear
                End If
End Sub
```

When I try with Outlook instead of OneNote, it works fine and Outlook closes. I was wondering if it was because OneNote is not an application that supports automation through VBA. As shown in the below link, the table at the bottom of the page lists all the top-level Office objects Ican reference and their class names and OneNote is not among them:

[Creation of Object Variables to Automate Another Office Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140508%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Any ideas, suggestions on how to close the application (not the notebooks themselves, only the application running.. )

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to get rid of `On Error Resume Next` you might be able to debug this...

Comment: gives me error 429: ActiveX component can't create object or return reference to this object. Does that mean that OneNote is an Office object I can't reference ?

Comment: Which line raises taht error? `GetObject` or `.Quit`?

Comment: .GetObject raises the error

Comment: Use `CreateObject` to get OneNote application, or dimension it as an object variable and use the `CreateObject` or Dim as New` methods.  `Quit` will still fail. It is simply not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good resource for handling NoteNote:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377180(v=office.14)

and in general:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377180(v=office.14)

Comment: That gives information about how to close the notebooks, which is not what I need to know. I need to leave the notebooks open but only to close the application OneNote.

Comment: `Notebooks` belong to OneNote. You can't leave the Notebooks open while closing the OneNote application.  That would be like asking how to leave a `Workbook` open, while closing Excel.Application.  It can't be done.  I think this answer has the information you need.  Otherwise, try enabling reference to the OneNote library and use intellisense to help you through. YOu can always revert to a late-binding approach when you are satisfied the code is working as expected.

Comment: I know it may sound strange but OneNote allows to keep the Notebooks open and close the application. When the user reopens OneNote, he will find all of his Notebooks opened. If I use `oneNote.CloseNotebook notebookID` in the code, it will close the notebooks allright but won't close OneNote application. After that line of code the user is left starring at OneNote with no Notebook open..

Answer (score 0):

OneNote Application interface (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg649853%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) does not have a Quit method. That is why it won't work. What you can do instead is to close the OneNote window, which is somewhat tricky. Here are some instructions and sample code:

- **Get the OneNote window handle:** The application object has a `CurrentWindow` member which then has a `WindowHandle` member that is a `HWND` to the current OneNote window.
- **Get the top level window:** This handle is typically a child window of the OneNote window so you need to call `GetAncestor` with `GA_ROOT` to get the top level window
- **Close the window:** You can send `WM_CLOSE` to the top level window to close it. Of course if it is displaying a dialog box or busy in another way, it may not respond to this.

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAncestor Lib "user32.dll" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal gaFlags As Long) As Long

  Private Const GA_ROOT As Long = 2
  Private Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

  Sub test()
      ' Create Application Object
      Dim app As Object
      Set app = CreateObject("OneNote.Application")

      ' Get the window handle
      Dim hwnd As Long
      hwnd = app.Windows.CurrentWindow.WindowHandle

      ' Get the top level window
      Dim hwndRoot As Long
      hwndRoot = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOT)

      ' Close it
      PostMessage hwndRoot, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0&
  End Sub
  ```

This won't be enough if there are multiple OneNote windows around. For that case you can enumerate the `Windows` collection and do this for each `Window` object in it.